# what should i use as parameter in add() and sub() in if statement?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I want to use user input for calculation and i have define add(*args) and sub(*args) but if i write *args in add() in if statement then its show error:args not defined
and if write m then its shows me value of m not total....

```
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for a in args:
        total += a
    print(total)

def sub(*args):
    total = 0
    for a in args:
        total -= a
    print(total)

print('1-add\n2-sub')
n=int(input("enter choice:"))
counter = int(input("enter no of No.to be calculated:"))
if n == 1:
    for i in range(counter):
        m=int(input("enter no."))
    add()
elif n == 2:
    for i in range(counter):
        m = int(input("enter no."))
    sub()
else:
    print("invalid")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing anything when calling `add` and `sub` functions, nor saving all of the user input. You need to save the user input to a list and then pass the list to the functions. Note that you will also need to remove the `*` from the functions signatures as you want to pass in a list, not an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
def add(args):
    total = 0
    for a in args:
        total += a
    print(total)

def sub(args):
    total = 0
    for a in args:
        total -= a
    print(total)

.
.

if n == 1:
    li = []
    for i in range(counter):
        li.append(int(input("enter no.")))
    add(li)
elif n == 2:
    li = []
    for i in range(counter):
        m = li.append(int(input("enter no.")))
    sub(li)
```

Keep in mind you could make your code shorter (not necessarily more readable) using generators:

```
if n == 1:
    add(int(input()) for i in range(counter))
elif n == 2:
    sub(int(input()) for i in range(counter))
```

Comment: but how to append list in last 'if n == 1:
    add(int(input()) for i in range(counter))
elif n == 2:
    sub(int(input()) for i in range(counter))'

Comment: @Trunks I'm not sure I understand. You don't need to use `append` if you use this approach. There is no list to `append` to.